# mongodb Modified field name may not start with $

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I manage my db with mongodb using node.js

In server.js, this code evoke error

```
TB_LolCombinationOfChampion.update({},{ $set: { $set: { win: 23445123123 }}},{multi: true},function (err, raw) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
                        });
```

I get this error

> { [MongoError: Modified field name may not start with $]   
> name:
>   'MongoError',   
> err: 'Modified field name may not start with $',
>   code: 15896,   
> n: 0,   
> connectionId: 601,   
> ok: 1 } 
>   
> The raw response
>   from Mongo was  null

Why this error evoke and how I avoid this error?

Comment: You have a nested `$set` in the update document, consider removing the outer `$set` document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you repeated $set twice
Instead of

```
{ $set: { $set: { win: 23445123123 }}}
```

Do

```
{ $set: { win: 23445123123 }}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TB_LolCombinationOfChampion.update({},{ $set: { win: 23445123123 }},{multi: true},function (err, raw) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
                        });
```

Remove extra $set and try.